# "No available constructor" when calling AutoMapper's Persist().InsertOrUpdate()

Tags: automapper, ef-core-2.1

I have a simple object with a default constructor. The objects I'm mapping to and from are both defined exactly the same and I've configured a mapper for them. Everything works fine getting the object from the database.

```
public class Tag
{
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Guid TagId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If I call `Mapper.Instance.Map(tagFrom, tagTo);` everything works fine, but if I call `dbContext.Tags.Persist().InsertOrUpdate(tag);` I get this error.

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
>   Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
>   For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>
> AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be mapped using the current configuration.
>
> AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be mapped using the current configuration.
>   Tag -> Expression`1 (Destination member list)
>   AKS.Common.Models.Tag -> System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[[System.Func`2[[AKS.AppCore.Entities.Tag, AKS.AppCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties:
>
> Parameters
>
> No available constructor.

Seems like it's saying I have no default constructor, but clearly there is one. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Package Versions:
AutoMapper 8.0.0
AutoMapper.Collections 5.0.0
AutoMapper.Collections.EntityFrameworkCore 0.2.0

Comment: There is no Persist or InsertOrUpdate in AutoMapper. The problem is with whatever that other code does.

Comment: Are you using [AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFrameworkCore/)? What version? Also the exception shows different entity from the post - `TopicEdit`, and also `Expression<Func<TopicEdit, bool>>`, so make sure the code you post reproduces the issue.

Comment: I updated the question with the error message for mapping Tag objects. I get the same error with all objects, but have been working with the Tag since it's simple. I also added the versions of the Automapper packages I'm referencing

Comment: I was able to reproduce it. It goes away if you add `CreateMap<Tag, Tag>()` to AM configuration. However there seems to be some equivalency expression bug, so the feature is not working at all (does wrong things because the expression is `GuidX == GuidX`, e.g. `true`, so `FirstOrDefault()` will return random item rather than the one that needs to be updated/deleted). Consider posting an issue to their tracker.

Comment: Could you share that repro? I'm trying to create a unit test that reproduces, and possibly see if I can submit a PR. But I'm having a hard time reproducing outside my larger project.

Comment: Ok, I have a simple repro now. It's something about the way I'm configuring the Mapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bug in AutoMapper.Collections.EntityFrameworkCore, or it may have been caused by my own misuse.

I was configuring my Mapper with the following code

```
var cfg = new MapperConfigurationExpression();

cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
cfg.UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel<MyDbContext>();

cfg.CreateMap<TagDto, TagEntity>().ReverseMap();
```

Then I was trying to validate my mapping config with this code before intializing the mapper.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg);
config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

Mapper.Initialize(cfg);
```

If I remove the lines where I create a `MapperConfiguration` and use that to `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` then calls to `InsertOrUpdate()` work.

I also found that I can call `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` if I initialize my mapper first, then call that method on the `Mapper.Instance`

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg);
Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```